External SSD wont mount, sonoma os
I recently bought an external SSD and I have macbook air m1 with sonoma 14.5
The SSD does not mount. I tried forced mounting it through the terminal.


Is "AL SSD Media" the SSD you bought? Did you try to connect it to another computer, to check whether it works there?

it is AL SSD. I did try to open it in my ACER laptop and it was fine until I click something. Then, now both ACER and Macbook it is not showing.

Maybe it is just broken on arrival, and you could get a replacement?

I am now able to see it in microsoft. It was wrong file type. But still I cant mount it.

The mount fails because the drive isn't formated with HFS (which makes sense). Which filesystem did you format it to, on which computer?

I think it’s in a file system macos does not support.

exFAT and I formatted in windos
